# Change last word on line in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim to edit C code, and I enjoy using `c<movement>` to quickly change parts of my file.  In particular, I find things like `c2W` useful to "change two space-delimited words."

But there's one use case that has escaped me: when my cursor is at the last character of a word, the command `cb`, "change back a word," does not delete the last character of the word I want to edit.  This makes sense, as the cursor was technically before that last character, but it's not what I want.

Here's what happens, with the cursor indicated by `|`:

Start with:

```
This is just a typ|ical series of words
```

I would like to change "typical" to "different."  I press `e`:

```
This is just a typica|l series of words
```

And then `cb`:

```
This is just a |l series of words
```

Now there's a hanging `l` (a lowercase L, to be clear) left over! That's not what I wanted.

The more astute of you have already noticed that I could in this example simply have used the combination `bcw`, which would put my cursor before the beginning of the word, and then changed through the whole word.  True! But what if I had wanted to change "words" to "strings?"

Start with:

```
This is just a typ|ical series of words
```

I would like to change "words" to "strings."  I press `$`:

```
This is just a typical series of word|s
```

Same problem! Pressing `cb` will leave a hanging "s" (although in this example that would be fine, since "strings" ends in "s" anyways).  Of course, I could press `bcw`, but that's one additional key, and thus unacceptable.

Do I just have to live with this incredible hardship?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> ("inner word") motion to select the whole word the cursor is currently positioned in. So combined with the <kbd>c</kbd> ("change") command, that'd leave you with <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

That would also apply to your first example: instead of first moving forward to the end of word with <kbd>e</kbd> and then using <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to change the backwards word, you could also use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> from your current position.

Comment: Thanks! I should've figured that out... Also, I chose your answer because it is the clearest and most well laid out.  The other two answers are also quite correct.

Comment: Why do you like this better than `bcw` which you rejected in your original question because it was too much typing?

Answer (score 5):

Try one of these guys: <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

This way you can replace word while your cursor is in the middle of the word.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `a` choice as well.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

`ciw` - change inner words.